# Bug or feature for a cosmetic change in Pivotal Tracker?

Tags: agile, agile-project-management, pivotaltracker

If I need to fix something cosmetic in my application (e.g. fixing the color of an element), should this be marked as a bug or as a feature in Pivotal Tracker?

Note: even though it's cosmetic, that doesn't mean that this fix will be trivial.

Answer (score 3):

The simplicity of the issue should not determine where it goes in your issue tracker.

I would say it depends upon how you view the color of the element.  If it strictly 'we decided indigo would be better than sky blue' I would probably call that an enhancement.  If it is something like 'all of our new members show up blue, but these are coming up red' that would be a bug.
And if it's 'Our theme is indigo, but this element is sky blue and breaks application consistency' I would also consider that a bug.

Comment: Valid point! It certainly is possible for color to be a bug. And as written, "fixing the color" does sound like a bug. If something isn't working as expected, or to spec, that is a bug. I retract my previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Feature.</strike> A bug is something obstructing functionality. If this is new functionality, it's a feature.

Edited: I take it back! My new answer is: It all depends! If something isn't working to spec, or as expected, then it's probably a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel it is a bug it is a bug. If you feel it's a feature it's a feature.

Longer version: if you think it is a feature mark it us such. If you feel this is something that was improperly implemented or doesn't work as it should or simply breaks down it is a bug. Either way it is work to be done in a sprint, so just make sure you do it. There is no right way that is universal to all circumstances, just make sure you have a shared understanding of what is a bug and what is not within your team and stick to that understanding.